# Create object in Google Cloud Storage from Text to Speech Response with Adalo

Tags: json, api, google-cloud-storage, httprequest

I'm building an app with Adalo and I created a custom action where I create a Text to Speech file. In the API response I get "audioContent". Now I would like to make an API call where I create a new object in Google Cloud Storage with the audioContent. I already have my endpoint (https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKET/o), the method (POST) and these query parameters: name=test, uploadType=media and contentType=audio/mpeg. What do I need to put into the JSON body for the request?

```
{"audioContent": "(binary data)"}
```

something like this? Please help!

Best regards,
Ben

Comment: Still struggling with this... Any ideas?

Comment: Would really need a solution! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the response from Text to Speech as a text file that contains `{"audioContent": "(binary data)"}`, you should decode it to whatever format you indicated at your request in Text to Speech. You can decode it this way (Let us say you indicated MP3 in your request):

```
base64 your_file_that_contains_your_audiocontent.txt -d > your_audio.mp3
```

NOTE: by default Text to Speech encode the content to base64, hence the decoding using base64.

Once you get your audio file, you won't be needing a JSON body for the request. See [uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects) for reference: Just send a POST request with the following parameters:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @/your/local/path/your_audio.mp3 \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: audio/mpeg" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=your_audio.mp3"
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!! Ok, and what if I can't save the txt or mp3 file locally? Can I somehow include the decoding in the POST request or something like that? Or how can I decode the binary data to mp3 in an HTTP request? Thanks again!

Comment: @beng I think you will still need to save the files locally since uploading files to GCS is copying a local file to cloud. You can post a new question for this so that the community can share their ideas :)

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you. It's just that I'm working with Adalo and I can't save files in the database. One last question: How can I save the txt file to GCS and then upload it to GCS as mp3? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @beng This is what I can think of right now. If it is possible 1.) store the text to speech response to a variable 2.) convert it using a base64 converter in your script 3.) try to check [streaming uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#rest-apis) to upload the file without saving it locally.